# Add a where condition (attribute) on a ArcGIS REST API FeatureService Layer applyEdits request

Tags: arcgis-server, feature-service

I am looking for a way to add a where condition (attribute) on a ArcGIS REST API FeatureService Layer applyEdits request

The idea is to filter the applyEdits executed on client side (ArcGIS JS Web App). The user can see everything and modify as well but the request must be intercepted and checked if the applyEdits are allowed against an attribute filter (where condition)
my environnment is based on ArcGIS Server 10.6 and ArcGIS JS 3.22.

Comment: Esri provides an SDK to develop Server Object Interceptors on the server side.  If you had control over the server this would be a worth considering.

Comment: my problem is that i don' t have control over the server side. i have to implement it in an "interceptor" (proxy) or i can consider to implement this on client side.